# BIRT - getPersistentGlobalVariable gives only last row

Tags: javascript, java, sql, eclipse, birt

I have table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading1       |     Heading2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I am setting:

```
var results = dataSetRow["Heading1"];
report.Context.setPersistentGlobalVariable("results2",results);
var test=report.Context.getPersistentGlobalVariable("results2");
```

and ***test*** consists only of the last row value which is ***2*** when I use it in another data set.
How can I set all column values to ***persistentGlobalVariable*** or access them one by one via BIRT script? I need to pass those values to another DataSet somehow.

Comment: is this supposed to be java or javascript?

Comment: BIRT uses JavaScript (also known as EcmaScript) for expressions, business logic, and integration with application-specific Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a collection to store the individual values.
With every script evaluation, the previously assigned value will be overwritten and you will only keep the last one. For example, you could create an array and keep it as a global variable in the report context